# Date from string timezone not tally using DateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, dateformatter

Code:

```
let isoDate = "1981-02-20T10:44:00+0800"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

var localTimeZoneAbbreviation: String { return TimeZone.current.abbreviation() ?? "" }

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: isoDate)!
dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Output:
[image]

Why does the date output timezone is +07:30 instead of +0800 as defined in the date string and also TimeZone.current? Anybody can explain this?

Comment: Note that `TimeZone.current` is the default value...

Answer (score 0):

The timezone format is not `Z` but `ZZZ`

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"
```

Comment: that also did not fix the timezone to +0800

Comment: I just edit my answer. The timezone format is 3 Z not 4.

Comment: changed the Z format to various combinations. still the same output GMT+0730

Comment: I just check once more and I think it works but the print method return the result with +0000 but time is 02:44 and not 10:44 so it added 8 hours. If you manipulate the same object in your code. Everything should work fine.